# Flutter datasets. How can I convert Map<double, double> to double with a single list of coordinates, and plug that into a map?

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter, dart

So far, this is what I have:

```
Map<double,double> m = (await sheet.values.map.column(3, fromRow:2)).map((key, value)=>
    MapEntry(double.parse(key), double.parse(value)));
Map<double,double> m2 = (await sheet.values.map.column(4, fromRow:2)).map((key, value)=>
    MapEntry(double.parse(key), double.parse(value)));
```

error when called here:

```
    setState(() async {

      _markers.addAll([
        Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId("[0]"),
            infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'test 1' + " " + "test"),
            position: LatLng(m, m2)),
      ]
      );
    });
  }
```

The error is:

> The argument type 'Map<double, double>' can't be assigned to the
> parameter type 'double'.

I'm pulling latitude and longitude from a google spreadsheet. No issues with printing the data. However, getting it into position: LatLng(m, m2)) is another story. How can I get it in there? How do I convert to double only?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I'm dumb. LatLng requires [" something "] as shown below:

> ```
>         position: LatLng(m["test"], m2["test"])),
> ```